# R - if-else applied to a list

Tags: r, list, if-statement, apply

I am new to R, so it may be that some of concepts are not fully correct... 
I have a set of files that I read into a list (here just shown the first 3 lines of each):

```
myfiles<-lapply(list.files(".",pattern="tab",full.names=T),read.table,skip="#")
myfiles
[[1]]
       V1  V2         V3
1   10001  33 -0.0499469
2   30001  65  0.0991478
3   50001  54  0.1564400

[[2]]
       V1  V2        V3
1   10001  62 0.0855260
2   30001  74 0.1536640
3   50001  71 0.1020960

[[3]]
       V1  V2          V3
1   10001  49 -0.04661360
2   30001  65  0.16961500
3   50001  61  0.07089600
```

I want to apply an ifelse condition in order to substitute values in columns and then return exactly the same list. However, when I do this:

```
myfiles<-lapply(myfiles,function(x) ifelse(x$V2>50, x$V3, NA))
myfiles
[[1]]
 [1]         NA  0.0991478  0.1564400

[[2]]
 [1] 0.0855260 0.1536640 0.1020960

[[3]]
 [1]          NA  0.16961500  0.07089600
```

it does in fact what I want to, but returns only the columns where the function was applied, and I want it to return the same list as before, with 3 columns (but with the substitutions).

I guess there should be an easy way to do this with some variant of "apply", but I was not able to find it or solve it.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to replace the `V3` column, just modify your function: `lapply(myfiles,function(x) {x$V3<-ifelse(x$V2>50, x$V3, NA);x})`. If you want to add another column called `newcolumnname`, just replace `x$V3` with `x$newcolumnname` in the above command.

Comment: Do you want to replace the values in `V2` or `V3`?

Comment: I want to replace values in V3 based on a condition on V2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lapply` and `transform`/`within`. There are three possibilities:

- **a)** `ifelse`

  ```
  lapply(myfiles, transform, V3 = ifelse(V2 > 50, V3, NA))
  ```
- **b)** mathematical operators (potentially more efficient)

  ```
  lapply(myfiles, transform, V3 = NA ^ (V2 <= 50) * V3)
  ```
- **c)** `is.na<-`

  ```
  lapply(myfiles, within, is.na(V3) <- V2 < 50)
  ```

The result

```
[[1]]
     V1 V2        V3
1 10001 33        NA
2 30001 65 0.0991478
3 50001 54 0.1564400

[[2]]
     V1 V2       V3
1 10001 62 0.085526
2 30001 74 0.153664
3 50001 71 0.102096

[[3]]
     V1 V2       V3
1 10001 49       NA
2 30001 65 0.169615
3 50001 61 0.070896
```

Comment: Are there any preferences regarding processing times for these 3 possibilities? I am going for the transform+ifelse (a) because it seems more readable to me. Thanks

Comment: @PedroA I would prefer the third solution. The `ifelse` version is clearly the most inefficient one.

Comment: Why '<-' does not work here, i.e.: lapply(myfiles, transform, V3 <- ifelse(V2 > 50, V3, NA))  ? It just shows original myfiles, without any NA values.

Comment: @rnso You have to use `=` instead of `<-` in the `transform` function.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this helps

```
 lapply(myfiles,within, V3 <- ifelse(V2 >50, V3, NA))


 #[[1]]
 #    V1 V2        V3
 #1 10001 33        NA
 #2 30001 65 0.0991478
 #3 50001 54 0.1564400

 #[[2]]
 #    V1 V2       V3
 #1 10001 62 0.085526
 #2 30001 74 0.153664
 #3 50001 71 0.102096

#[[3]]
#     V1 V2       V3
#1 10001 49       NA
#2 30001 65 0.169615
#3 50001 61 0.070896
```

#### Update

Another option would be to read the files using `fread` from `data.table` which would be fast

```
library(data.table)
files <- list.files(pattern='tab')
lapply(files, function(x) fread(x)[V2<=50,V3:=NA] )
#[[1]]
#     V1 V2        V3
#1: 10001 33        NA
#2: 30001 65 0.0991478
#3: 50001 54 0.1564400

#[[2]]
#     V1 V2       V3
#1: 10001 62 0.085526
#2: 30001 74 0.153664
#3: 50001 71 0.102096

#[[3]]
#     V1 V2       V3
#1: 10001 49       NA
#2: 30001 65 0.169615
#3: 50001 61 0.070896
```

Or as @Richie Cotton mentioned, you could also bind the datasets together using `rbindlist` and then do the operation in one step.

```
 library(tools)
 dt1 <- rbindlist(lapply(files, function(x) 
      fread(x)[,id:= basename(file_path_sans_ext(x))] ))[V2<=50, V3:=NA]

 dt1
 #     V1 V2        V3   id
 #1: 10001 33        NA tab1
 #2: 30001 65 0.0991478 tab1
 #3: 50001 54 0.1564400 tab1
 #4: 10001 62 0.0855260 tab2
 #5: 30001 74 0.1536640 tab2
 #6: 50001 71 0.1020960 tab2
 #7: 10001 49        NA tab3
 #8: 30001 65 0.1696150 tab3
 #9: 50001 61 0.0708960 tab3
```

Comment: Why '=' does not work here:  lapply(myfiles,within, V3 = ifelse(V2 >50, V3, NA))  ? It throws error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : argument is missing, with no default

Comment: @rnso May be this link gives some ideas http://r4stats.com/2013/01/22/comparing-tranformation-styles/

Answer (score 1):

This seems harder than it should be because you are working with a list of data frames rather than a single data frame.  You can combine all the data frames into a single one using `rbind_all` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
# Some variable renaming for clarity:
# myfiles now refers to the file names; mydata now contains the data
myfiles <- list.files(pattern="tab", full.names=TRUE) 
mydata <- lapply(myfiles, read.table, skip="#")

# Get the number of rows in each data frame
n_rows <- vapply(mydata, nrow, integer(1))
# Combine the list of data frames into a single data frame
all_mydata <- rbind_all(mydata)
# Add an identifier to see which data frame the row came from.
all_mydata$file <- rep(myfiles, each = n_rows)

# Now update column 3
is.na(all_mydata$V3) <- all_mydata$V2 < 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an id column for each df and binding them together:

```
for(i in 1:3) myfiles[[i]]$id = i
ddf = myfiles[[1]]
for(i in 2:3) ddf = rbind(ddf, myfiles[[i]])
```

Then apply changes on composite df and split it back again:

```
ddf$V3 = ifelse(ddf$V2>50, ddf$V3, NA)
myfiles = lapply(split(ddf, ddf$id), function(x) x[1:3])

myfiles
$`1`
     V1 V2        V3
1 10001 33        NA
2 30001 65 0.0991478
3 50001 54 0.1564400

$`2`
      V1 V2       V3
11 10001 62 0.085526
21 30001 74 0.153664
31 50001 71 0.102096

$`3`
      V1 V2       V3
12 10001 49       NA
22 30001 65 0.169615
32 50001 61 0.070896
```